# Active directory replication partner question

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I want to setup an additional DC as a replication partner on my windows domain (all servers 2008 R2 x64).

However, I always have issues with DNS configuration. Before and after deploying the additional DC, what steps do I need to take to configure the servers? (I know how to deploy the DC but what best practises are there?).

Thanks

Comment: What is your exact question? Are you asking how to configure DNS on the new DC?

Answer (score 2):

If DNS is integrated to AD then you don't have to do anything.  Simply add the new DC and everything will replicate assuming they are in the same site.

Answer (score 1):

Add the server to the domain, reboot, and then run dcpromo.

Replication between DCs is automatic.